# Arrow function should not return assignment no-return-assign

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-form

My code is working correctly in the app however, before commit husky runs and gives out the error saying  "Arrow function should not return assignment  no-return-assign"

```
           <Field name='dob' label='dateOfBirth'
              placeholder=''
              onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD'}
            />
```

Comment: Just enclose function body in brackets. `(e) => {e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD'}`

Comment: Instead of returning an assignment, you should put curly braces around what you're returning
onFocus={(e) => {e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD'}}

Comment: arrow functions has an implicit return if there's no curly brackets, that's why you're seeing that error

Comment: thank  you guys, it worked...that was was pretty quick

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the brackets in your arrow function, it will implicitly return the statement. In this case, the compiler is warning you that you are returning the assignment, which is not allowed (I'm guessing to avoid a situation where you are attempting to check for equality and mistakenly type only a single `=` instead of `===`)

You can surround the function body in brackets to avoid this issue:

```
onFocus={(e) => { e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD'} }
```

Check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions) for more information on arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

As several people mention in comments, the issue is that you're using

```
(e) => e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD'
```

which is roughly equivalent to

```
anon_func = function (e) {
    return e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD';
}
```

because `(args) => <expression>` means to evaluate the expression and return the result.

Contrary to jakemingolla's answer, this *is* legal; it returns 'MM/YYYY'DD' which doesn't matter in this situation since you don't care about any return value.  That's why it "works".  But it is generally regarded as poor style, which is why your pre-commit checks flag it.

What you want is `(args) => {<function-body>}`, which (like any directly-declared function body) just returns undefined if you don't explicitly return something.  That is

```
(e) => {e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD';}
```

is roughly like

```
anon_func = function (e) {
    e.target.placeholder = 'MM/YYYY/DD';
}
```

which is what you want.

Comment: > Contrary to jakemingolla's answer, this is legal; it returns 'MM/YYYY'DD' which doesn't matter in this situation since you don't care about any return value. That's why it "works". But it is generally regarded as poor style, which is why your pre-commit checks flag it.

I'm not really sure my answer implies it was illegal - nor does your answer provide an explanation for why the compiler matched this to begin with outside of denoting "poor style"

Comment: @jakemingolla - "the compiler is warning you that you are returning the assignment, which is not allowed".  So yes, you didn't *imply* it was illegal; you *said* so.  Also, the style warning was not flagged by a compiler (there isn't one involved), and "poor style" *is* the reason it was flagged.  So if you're looking for a reason "outside of denoting 'poor style'", then you need to adjust your expectations.