# ReactJS es-lint: Return statement should not contain assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, arrow-functions

**es-lint is failing for this case:** Return statement should not contain assignment  *no-return-assign*

I've looked into this thread but to no avail: [Arrow function should not return assignment no-return-assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974912/arrow-function-should-not-return-assignment-no-return-assign)

What can I do here to satisfy es-lint?

**My State Variable**

```js
const [monthlyIncidents, setMonthlyIncidents] = useState([
    // monthlyIncidents[0] -> January ... monthlyIncidents[11] -> December
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
  ])
```

**How I'm Updating State**

```js
setMonthlyIncidents((prevIncidents) => {
   return { ...prevIncidents, [incidentMonth]: monthlyIncidents[incidentMonth] += 1 }
})
```

Comment: Btw after update like this monthlyIncidents will be object instead of array. I am not sure if that's what you really want.

Comment: You were right on that point Pavel. Thank you for the insight! @PavelKratochvil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is it is seeing the `+= 1` as assignment (which coincidentally is also a state mutation).

You may be able to get by with *just* adding one to the current state. This likely converts your array to an object, so use caution.

```
setMonthlyIncidents((prevIncidents) => {
  return {
    ...prevIncidents,
    [incidentMonth]: prevIncidents[incidentMonth] + 1,
  }
})
```

Typically with a state update like this it is preferable to map the existing state to the next state and update the element. It looks like `incidentMonth` is simply an array index, so you can match the incident by index. This guarantees the state remains an array.

```
setMonthlyIncidents((prevIncidents) =>
  prevIncidents.map((incident, index) =>
    incident + index === incidentMonth ? 1 : 0
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Drew. Both methods worked, and you were right about the first one converting the array to an object. Also, I would have never thought of using the map function in this situation. It is a lot more flexible!

Answer (score 1):

TRY

setMonthlyIncidents(
{
...prevIncidents,
[incidentMonth]: prevIncidents[incidentMonth] + 1,

}).

you just need to not assign state while returning it.Plus, I really don't get why you are  creating a whole new function to set the state? (what does the `setStateVariable` hook do?). You can also disable es-lint for that line.